# How to redirect frontend if admin username password is wrong

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, login

I am new to magento, I am learning step by step with all your help. Thanks..

I have done admin login from the frontend. I have separate login for admin at front end footer, I did it successfully but when user-name and password is wrong then it redirect magento admin login form and display the error.

I don't need like that, I have to redirect it to front with error message.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Put your code here.

Answer (score 2):

If you do the login with a form that points to `/admin/index/login`, you can add an additional hidden field to the form, for example `is_login_from_frontend` and check if this parameter is set in an observer for `controller_action_postdispatch_admin_index_login` like this:

```
public function redirectToFrontendAfterLoginFromFrontend(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
        return; // never redirect if login was successful
    }
    $controller = $this->getControllerAction();
    if ($controller->getRequest()->getPost('is_login_from_frontend')) {
        $controller->getResponse()->setRedirect($controller->getUrl('/'));
    }
}
```